# What happened to this pixel?

Tags: display, pixels, dead-pixel

I have what seems like a dead pixel on my screen, but when I take a picture of it and zoom in it looks different.

[image]

**[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz9Uw.jpg)**

Comment: Looks more like some contaminant or damage than a dead pixel, but it's really hard to tell from the pic

Comment: I cleaned the screen but it is still there.

Comment: Looks like it's inside